# Sort table column by date in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that's displayed on button click using ajax. Here's a code snippet:

```
myBtn.on("click", function() {
    displayTable();
});

function displayTable(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'url to a function in controller',
        type: "GET",
        //data: {val : val},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){  

            // some codes here

            $.each(data.documents, function(key, value){                        
                $("#myTable")
                .append(
                    "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td class='text-center'>" +                       
                        value.title +
                    "</td><td class='text-center'>" +               
                        value.time1.replace(/-/g, "/") +
                    "</td><td class='text-center'>" +                  
                        value.time2.replace(/-/g, "/") +
                    "</td></tr>"
                );
            });
        }
    });
}
```

After this, a table is displayed but it is not sorted by date (`value.time2`). I tried this but not working:

```
$("#myTable thead tr").find('th').eq(3).sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date($(a).value.time2) > new Date($(b).value.time2);
});
```

Do you have any idea how to do this? How do I sort it by date (`value.time2`)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to request the server to sort the values for you. However, if you need to perform this on client side, you can simply sort `data.documents` before adding it to the page. For example:

```
        data.documents = data.documents.map(function(item) {
            // Fix display
            item.time1 = item.time1.replace(/-/g, "/");
            item.time2 = item.time2.replace(/-/g, "/");
            return item;
        });
        data.documents.sort(function(a, b) {
            // Custom sorting function
            return new Date(a.time2) > new Date(b.time2);
        });

        $.each(data.documents, function(key, value){                        
            $("#myTable")
            .append(
                "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'><td class='text-center'>" +                       
                    value.title +
                "</td><td class='text-center'>" +               
                    value.time1 +
                "</td><td class='text-center'>" +                  
                    value.time2 +
                "</td></tr>"
            );
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this one out. Will get back to you.

Comment: Ethelene Laverne, please see the update. I've added missing `return item;` to `map` call.

Comment: @EtheleneLaverne also, can you show some example JSON that you get from the server?